# How to loop through CSV files, skip first 5 lines and write to a consolidated CSV

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a bunch of CSV files in a directory. I want to loop through each and every file, get rid of the first 5 lines in each file and write the remaining lines to a CSV file "Consolidated_wo_first5.csv". My files are ";" separated.

My windows script:

```
set sourcedir=C:\transport\in
set targetdir=C:\transport\out

for %%F in (%sourcedir%\*.csv) do (for %%f "skip=5 tokens=* delims=;" in (%%~nf) do echo %%a)>>%targetdir%\Consolidated_wo_first5.csv
```

Sample input file:

```
Row1 ;Row1;Row1
Row2;Row2;Row2
Row3;Row3;Row3
Row4;Row4;Row4
Row5;Row5;Row5
Row6;Row6;Row6
Row7;Row7;Row7
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: According to the "duplicates": That's not duplicate data, that's command repetition. Aacini said `NOTE: Insert @echo off line at beginning of your code! ` This supresses the command repetition.

Comment: I strongly recommend to delete the last part (starting at *»Using Aacini's script works, [...]«*) from the question, because that's nothing else than a duplicate comment on Aacini's answer, which does not contribute anything useful to the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some minor details in your code:

```
set sourcedir=C:\transport\in
set targetdir=C:\transport\out

(for %%F in (%sourcedir%\*.csv) do (
   for /F "usebackq skip=5 delims=" %%f in ("%%F") do (
      echo %%f
   )
)) > %targetdir%\Consolidated_wo_first5.csv
```

- The %%f and %%F are misplaced.
- The /F option was missed in second FOR, and the %%f was in wrong place
- If you want complete lines, it is easier to use "delims="
- Is convenient to enclose the file name in quotes, and in this case the "usebackq" option is required.
- The program run faster if the >>append redirection is changed by a >replace one, and in this case the whole FOR must be enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: We're getting there! But I get in the output file kind of duplicates. Each line comes twice like:

`C:\transport>(echo File 1 Row 9 Column 1;File 1 Row 9 Column 2;File 1 Row 9 Column 3 ) 

File 1 Row 9 Column 1;File 1 Row 9 Column 2;File 1 Row 9 Column 3`

How can I avoid the first line?

Comment: Excuse me. You can not post a supposed output if you don't post the input! What do you think if I say "It works correctly here, with _my data_"? **`:/`** Please, post a small data example that show the error. Edit the question; do NOT post data in comments! **NOTE**: Insert `@echo off` line at beginning of your code!

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Works perfect now after adding "@echo off".

Comment: If this answer aids you, may I ask you to select it (click on the green check-mark) and also upvote it?